# vb express 2010 populating array

Tags: vb.net

it doesnt like my code:

```
    Dim n As Integer
    Dim flag As Boolean
    Dim i
    Dim x() As Integer

    n = InputBox("How many numbers do you want to be sorted?")

    For i = 1 To n - 1 Step 1
        x(i) = InputBox("Please enter a record")
    Next i
```

I want to put values into x()

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a ReDim to specify the size of `x` as soon as you know it (ie after your first InputBox):

```
n = InputBox("How many numbers do you want to be sorted?")
ReDim x(n - 1)
```

Also, your For loop will be simpler to handle if it's zero based as in:

```
For i = 0 To n - 1 Step 1
```